# openssl smime sign and encrypt loads

Tags: openssl, smime

I am trying to investigate openssl S/MIME in order to both sign and encrypt loads to be transfered over an untrusted network.
Loads need to be protected in authenticity and confidentiality.
I have already implemented a bash script rather long before discovering that all steps may be accomplished by a single openssl smime command, but still, i am unsure about its working and usage. I have tried:

```
# Creation of a dummy CA and certificates:
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -sha512 -days 10 -key ca.key -out ca.pem
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 2 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout user.key -out user.pem

# Attempt (working) to sign using user certificate
openssl smime -sign -in binary -out binary.signed user.pem
```

Why on earth is it possible to sign using a public key?!
Or am i just fooling around? What is the proper way to do so?

```
# Attempt (not working, but can SMIME support this) to sign AND encrypt.
openssl smime -sign -encrypt -aes-256-cbc -in myLoad -out myLoad.enc.signed -signer user.pem
```

Is it possible for openssl smime subcommand to sign using my private key and encrypt using randomly generated symmetric key itself encrypted using the destination public key?

Many thanks for your help, Google seems to indicate it is indeed possible, still missing how to do that.

Comment: Encrypting with S/MIME actually means that a randomly generated symmetric key is used to encrypt (CEK= content encryption key). The symmetric key is then encrypted by the recipient's public key and attache to the message. This happens under the hood, so from the outside you just handle the asymmetric key.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment. Still, is it possible to sign and encrypt at the same time ? And why signing requires the (my) public key, shouldn't be my private key getting used for that purpose ?

Comment: By "at the same time", do you mean in one command? Not exactly, but you can pipe the result of signing into encrypting. Yes, for signing you should use the private key. May I suggest that you go to the [openssl-smime manual](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-smime.html) and scroll down to the excellent list of examples. Don't hesitate to come back if questions remain.

Comment: What version/build of openssl do you have? I have all major versions since 1.0.0, and in all of them `openssl smime -in validfile -out validfile certfile.pem` gives 'No signer certificate specified` which although true is incomplete (in versions below 1.1.0 it _also_ spits the usage message; in 1.1.0 up it just suggests `-help`). And `... -signer certfile.pem` on 1.0.x and 1.1.x gives `unable to load signing key file` plus `error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line` while 3.0 gives more simply `Could not read signing key from $file`. In short, yes signing requires privatekey.